# in a set transform to lowcase c++ errorC2664

Tags: c++, transform, lowercase, c2664

I'm trying to use STL function `transform` to transform all the strings in a set to lowcase. But I got an error of C2664. I wonder what the wrong with my code?

```
set<string> mydoc;
mydoc.insert("ABCD");
transform(mydoc.begin(), mydoc.end(), mydoc.begin(), ::tolower);
copy(mydoc.begin(), mydoc.end(), output);
```

Comment: Doesn't the [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c2664/info) explain well enough?

Comment: 1. What is the type each iterator of `set<string>` refers to (what is stored in the set)? 2. What is the type `tolower` expects?

Comment: @Pixelchemist 'ostream_iterator<string> output(cout, " \n");' is the iterator

Comment: @JoviZhihaoZhou: I mean in the `transform` statement. What is the type the iterator (result of `mydoc.begin()`) **refers** to (not the iterator type itself)? It refers to `std::string` as you iterate a set of `string`s. So you try to transform a set of string by passing a function that takes a **character** and not a string argument.

Comment: @Pixelchemist Got you! Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You cannot pass a `std::string` to `tolower`.
2. The C++11 `set` iterator is `const`.

Thus, you should probably apply `tolower` to each `string` when inserting it into the `set` instead of changing it afterwards because you'd have to waste time by reinserting every element into a sorted container.